# propertyException Could not find setter for this on class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

i'm stumbling an error when i tried to call my web service, here is the code

```
  package com.astra.adp.model;





import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
//@Table(name="all_customer_hist")
@Table(name="ALL_CUSTOMER_ENRICH_HIST_20170825")
public class AllCustomerHist {

    public AllCustomerHist(){}

    @Column(name = "REFF_FLAG")
    private String reffFlag;
    @Column(name = "REFF_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private Integer reffId;
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
    @NotNull
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    @NotNull
    private Date createdDate;
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", length = 255)
    private String customerId;
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "DOB", length = 255)
    private String dob;
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_PLACE", length = 255)
    private String birthPlace;
    @Column(name = "GENDER", length = 255)
    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "RELIGION", length = 255)
    private String religion;
    @Column(name = "EDUCATION", length = 255)
    private String education;
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_TYPE", length = 255)
    private String employeeType;
    @Column(name = "MARITAL_STATUS", length = 255)
    private String maritalStatus;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", length = 300)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 255)
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "KECAMATAN", length = 255)
    private String kecamatan;
    @Column(name = "KELURAHAN", length = 255)
    private String kelurahan;
    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE", length = 255)
    private String zipCode;
    @Column(name = "BPS_CODE", length = 255)
    private String bpsCode;
    @Column(name = "ID_TYPE", length = 255)
    private String idType;
    @Column(name = "ID_NUMBER", length = 255)
    private String idNumber;
    @Column(name = "NPWP", length = 255)
    private String npwp;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_1", length = 255)
    private String homePhone1;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_2", length = 255)
    private String homePhone2;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_3", length = 255)
    private String homePhone3;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_4", length = 255)
    private String homePhone4;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_5", length = 255)
    private String homePhone5;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_1", length = 255)
    private String officePhone1;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_2", length = 255)
    private String officePhone2;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_3", length = 255)
    private String officePhone3;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_4", length = 255)
    private String officePhone4;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_5", length = 255)
    private String officePhone5;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_1", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone1;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_2", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone2;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_3", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone3;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_4", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone4;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_5", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone5;
    @Column(name = "FAX_NUMBER_1", length = 255)
    private String faxNumber1;
    @Column(name = "FAX_NUMBER_2", length = 255)
    private String faxNumber2;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_1", length = 255)
    private String email1;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_2", length = 255)
    private String email2;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_3", length = 255)
    private String email3;
    @Column(name = "SRCTABLE", length = 255)
    private String srctable;
    @Column(name = "ADP_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private Integer adpId;
    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
//  @SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="SYSTEMID")
    @Column(name = "SYSTEM_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private Integer systemId;
    @Column(name = "NAME_RAW", length = 255)
    private String nameRaw;
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_TITLE", length = 8)
    private String customerTitle;
    @Column(name = "GENDERTITLE", length = 8)
    private String gendertitle;
    public String getReffFlag() {
        return reffFlag;
    }
    public void setReffFlag(String reffFlag) {
        this.reffFlag = reffFlag;
    }
    public Integer getReffId() {
        return reffId;
    }
    public void setReffId(Integer reffId) {
        this.reffId = reffId;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }
    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getBirthPlace() {
        return birthPlace;
    }
    public void setBirthPlace(String birthPlace) {
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getReligion() {
        return religion;
    }
    public void setReligion(String religion) {
        this.religion = religion;
    }
    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }
    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }
    public String getEmployeeType() {
        return employeeType;
    }
    public void setEmployeeType(String employeeType) {
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
    }
    public String getMaritalStatus() {
        return maritalStatus;
    }
    public void setMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus) {
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getKecamatan() {
        return kecamatan;
    }
    public void setKecamatan(String kecamatan) {
        this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
    }
    public String getKelurahan() {
        return kelurahan;
    }
    public void setKelurahan(String kelurahan) {
        this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    public String getBpsCode() {
        return bpsCode;
    }
    public void setBpsCode(String bpsCode) {
        this.bpsCode = bpsCode;
    }
    public String getIdType() {
        return idType;
    }
    public void setIdType(String idType) {
        this.idType = idType;
    }
    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }
    public String getNpwp() {
        return npwp;
    }
    public void setNpwp(String npwp) {
        this.npwp = npwp;
    }
    public String getHomePhone1() {
        return homePhone1;
    }
    public void setHomePhone1(String homePhone1) {
        this.homePhone1 = homePhone1;
    }
    public String getHomePhone2() {
        return homePhone2;
    }
    public void setHomePhone2(String homePhone2) {
        this.homePhone2 = homePhone2;
    }
    public String getHomePhone3() {
        return homePhone3;
    }
    public void setHomePhone3(String homePhone3) {
        this.homePhone3 = homePhone3;
    }
    public String getHomePhone4() {
        return homePhone4;
    }
    public void setHomePhone4(String homePhone4) {
        this.homePhone4 = homePhone4;
    }
    public String getHomePhone5() {
        return homePhone5;
    }
    public void setHomePhone5(String homePhone5) {
        this.homePhone5 = homePhone5;
    }
    public String getOfficePhone1() {
        return officePhone1;
    }
    public void setOfficePhone1(String officePhone1) {
        this.officePhone1 = officePhone1;
    }
    public String getOfficePhone2() {
        return officePhone2;
    }
    public void setOfficePhone2(String officePhone2) {
        this.officePhone2 = officePhone2;
    }
    public String getOfficePhone3() {
        return officePhone3;
    }
    public void setOfficePhone3(String officePhone3) {
        this.officePhone3 = officePhone3;
    }
    public String getOfficePhone4() {
        return officePhone4;
    }
    public void setOfficePhone4(String officePhone4) {
        this.officePhone4 = officePhone4;
    }
    public String getOfficePhone5() {
        return officePhone5;
    }
    public void setOfficePhone5(String officePhone5) {
        this.officePhone5 = officePhone5;
    }
    public String getMobilePhone1() {
        return mobilePhone1;
    }
    public void setMobilePhone1(String mobilePhone1) {
        this.mobilePhone1 = mobilePhone1;
    }
    public String getMobilePhone2() {
        return mobilePhone2;
    }
    public void setMobilePhone2(String mobilePhone2) {
        this.mobilePhone2 = mobilePhone2;
    }
    public String getMobilePhone3() {
        return mobilePhone3;
    }
    public void setMobilePhone3(String mobilePhone3) {
        this.mobilePhone3 = mobilePhone3;
    }
    public String getMobilePhone4() {
        return mobilePhone4;
    }
    public void setMobilePhone4(String mobilePhone4) {
        this.mobilePhone4 = mobilePhone4;
    }
    public String getMobilePhone5() {
        return mobilePhone5;
    }
    public void setMobilePhone5(String mobilePhone5) {
        this.mobilePhone5 = mobilePhone5;
    }
    public String getFaxNumber1() {
        return faxNumber1;
    }
    public void setFaxNumber1(String faxNumber1) {
        this.faxNumber1 = faxNumber1;
    }
    public String getFaxNumber2() {
        return faxNumber2;
    }
    public void setFaxNumber2(String faxNumber2) {
        this.faxNumber2 = faxNumber2;
    }
    public String getEmail1() {
        return email1;
    }
    public void setEmail1(String email1) {
        this.email1 = email1;
    }
    public String getEmail2() {
        return email2;
    }
    public void setEmail2(String email2) {
        this.email2 = email2;
    }
    public String getEmail3() {
        return email3;
    }
    public void setEmail3(String email3) {
        this.email3 = email3;
    }
    public String getSrctable() {
        return srctable;
    }
    public void setSrctable(String srctable) {
        this.srctable = srctable;
    }
    public Integer getAdpId() {
        return adpId;
    }
    public void setAdpId(Integer adpId) {
        this.adpId = adpId;
    }
    public Integer getSystemId() {
        return systemId;
    }
    public void setSystemId(Integer systemId) {
        this.systemId = systemId;
    }
    public String getNameRaw() {
        return nameRaw;
    }
    public void setNameRaw(String nameRaw) {
        this.nameRaw = nameRaw;
    }
    public String getCustomerTitle() {
        return customerTitle;
    }
    public void setCustomerTitle(String customerTitle) {
        this.customerTitle = customerTitle;
    }
    public String getGendertitle() {
        return gendertitle;
    }
    public void setGendertitle(String gendertitle) {
        this.gendertitle = gendertitle;
    }
    public AllCustomerHist(String reffFlag, Integer reffId, Date lastUpdatedDate, Date createdDate, String customerId,
            String name, String dob, String birthPlace, String gender, String religion, String education,
            String employeeType, String maritalStatus, String address, String city, String kecamatan, String kelurahan,
            String zipCode, String bpsCode, String idType, String idNumber, String npwp, String homePhone1,
            String homePhone2, String homePhone3, String homePhone4, String homePhone5, String officePhone1,
            String officePhone2, String officePhone3, String officePhone4, String officePhone5, String mobilePhone1,
            String mobilePhone2, String mobilePhone3, String mobilePhone4, String mobilePhone5, String faxNumber1,
            String faxNumber2, String email1, String email2, String email3, String srctable, Integer adpId,
            Integer systemId, String nameRaw, String customerTitle, String gendertitle) {
        super();
        this.reffFlag = reffFlag;
        this.reffId = reffId;
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.religion = religion;
        this.education = education;
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
        this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.bpsCode = bpsCode;
        this.idType = idType;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.npwp = npwp;
        this.homePhone1 = homePhone1;
        this.homePhone2 = homePhone2;
        this.homePhone3 = homePhone3;
        this.homePhone4 = homePhone4;
        this.homePhone5 = homePhone5;
        this.officePhone1 = officePhone1;
        this.officePhone2 = officePhone2;
        this.officePhone3 = officePhone3;
        this.officePhone4 = officePhone4;
        this.officePhone5 = officePhone5;
        this.mobilePhone1 = mobilePhone1;
        this.mobilePhone2 = mobilePhone2;
        this.mobilePhone3 = mobilePhone3;
        this.mobilePhone4 = mobilePhone4;
        this.mobilePhone5 = mobilePhone5;
        this.faxNumber1 = faxNumber1;
        this.faxNumber2 = faxNumber2;
        this.email1 = email1;
        this.email2 = email2;
        this.email3 = email3;
        this.srctable = srctable;
        this.adpId = adpId;
        this.systemId = systemId;
        this.nameRaw = nameRaw;
        this.customerTitle = customerTitle;
        this.gendertitle = gendertitle;
    }

}
```

this is my daoImpl class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<AllCustomerHist> getCustomers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(AllCustomerHist.class);
    return (List<AllCustomerHist>)criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AllCustomerHist.class)).list();
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/", method=RequestMethod.GET , headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<AllCustomerHist> getListCustomer(){
        List<AllCustomerHist> cust = allCustomerHistService.getCustomers();
        return cust;
    }
```

when i hit http://host:port/customer/ it throws:

> Exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for
>   this on class com.astra.adp.model.AllCustomerHist
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Root Cause
>
> org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for
>   this on class com.astra.adp.model.AllCustomerHist
>
> org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:66)
>
> org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.initialize(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:121)
>
> org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:84)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CriteriaLoader.java:148)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:753)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
>
> org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
>
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
>
> org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
>
> com.astra.adp.dao.AllCustomerHistDaoImpl.getCustomers(AllCustomerHistDaoImpl.java:45)
>
> com.astra.adp.service.AllCustomerHistServiceImpl.getCustomers(AllCustomerHistServiceImpl.java:31)
>
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy776.getCustomers(Unknown Source)
>
> com.astra.adp.controller.CustomerController.getListCustomer(CustomerController.java:29)
>
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

this problem occured when i'm migrating the datasource from oracle Db to ms sql server db, the code works fine with oracle db, but it doesnt work with sql server (all the table structure is same), and i believe i already have setter and getter in AllCustomerHist, what could be possibly wrong?

please dont marked as duplicate, i already read the similiar issue here, but none of them works

thank you

update, if i remove the alias transformer, the result is:

> [    null,    null,    null ]

i have no idea why?

Comment: try creating a no parameter constructor - the constructor with parameters should not be needed as the individual `setters` will be called

Comment: I don't know why you are using the AliasToBeanTransformer since you are querying and getting a List of AllCustomerHist, in any case may you post also your Hibernate configuration? In migration are you using the correct hibernate dialect?

Comment: @ScaryWombat will do it and post the result later, thanks

Comment: @AngeloImmediata this is the legacy api from my previous coworker, if i removed the transformer, it just throws nothing, no result and no error stack trace, yes i already modify the dialect, other methods works fine, only this method that throws an error

Comment: @ScaryWombat i removed the constructor parameters, but still the same

Comment: i guess this error due to the capitalization and underscore used in Column values. Try removing @ Column annotation or giving the same name as of variable in @ column value and Test.

Comment: another thing maybe that you used some ms sql reserved word for column name. In oracle it's OK while in ms sql it is not

Comment: @Nidhi257 will do, i'll inform you later

Comment: @AngeloImmediata i've checked it, no reserved word used here

Comment: Your Model looks perfect.Just restart eclipse,clean project directory ,remove old application from server and check again.

Comment: @Vaibs i did clean my project, restart eclipse even restarted my laptop, none of them works lol

Comment: all, i edited my post above, please check it